# Simple sound play with button iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk, audio

I have been trying for hours to make a simple sound playing after clicking a button, but I could not make it. After trying several tutorials, I followed one in this link:

http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/1126/xcode-4-tutorial-ios-ipad-iphone-20-playing-sound-with-button/

This is .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
@interface soundTestViewController : UIViewController{

}
-(IBAction) playSound;

@end
```

This is the .m file:

```
#import "soundTestViewController.h"

@implementation soundTestViewController
-(IBAction) playSound{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle=CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"mysound", CFSTR("mp3"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

**However, the Build Results gives errors:**

```
Build soundTest of project soundTest with configuration Debug

Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/soundTest.app/soundTest normal i386
cd /Users/joegeneric/Documents/soundTest
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk -L/Users/joegeneric/Documents/soundTest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/joegeneric/Documents/soundTest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/joegeneric/Documents/soundTest -filelist /Users/joegeneric/Documents/soundTest/build/soundTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/soundTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/soundTest.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -o /Users/joegeneric/Documents/soundTest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/soundTest.app/soundTest

ld: warning: in /Users/joegeneric/Documents/soundTest/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: warning: in /Users/joegeneric/Documents/soundTest/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols:
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      -[soundTestViewController playSound] in soundTestViewController.o
  "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID", referenced from:
      -[soundTestViewController playSound] in soundTestViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

[image]
Can you show what I did wrong or any other more simple working tutorial on making a sound play in iPhone SDK?

Comment: I think if you would have posted your code, It would have been easy to help..!

Answer (score 2):

[In addition to massimobio's correct answer]

The tutorial link you provided mentions Xcode 4 for iOS, but "setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6" line in your Build Results indicate your deployment target as Mac.

You need to change your Project Build Architecture to iOS and check that your target is an IOS, not OSX.

For e.g. to change your build architecture, click on your Project and select Build Settings to display the Base SDK. [image]

Also your IBAction is missing the sender. It should be declared in your controller header file as

```
-(IBAction) playSound:(id)sender;
```

and implemented in your controller .m file as

```
-(IBAction) playSound:(id)sender {
  // your code here
}
```

Also, don't forget to link your IBAction in your code to your XIB using control-drag to create an action-target pair.

Simplest Demo of playing sound is SysSound. It's available if you search Xcode documentation or via Apple Developer website under Sample Code.

Comment: My target is iOS 4.2, if I removed the method "playSound", it runs without any problem. but when adding the method, it gives error

Comment: I've amended my answer with more details. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but still does not work, probably my xcode version 3.2 is old

Comment: Don't think so. Both your AudioToolbox calls require iOS 2.0 and above so shouldn't be a problem. Did you fix your playSound method by adding ":(id) sender" like I stated in my answer above?

Comment: I did, but not help. It really made me crazy this weekend

Answer (score 1):

Did you add AudioToolbox framework to your Target,
and this import in your code?

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```